# Selecting certain values within a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, select

I have a string in which I need to extract all of the FieldRef names from the ViewField section of the string. They need to be input into an array. Been struggling with this for a while since im new to c#. Thanks.

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <OrderBy>
     <FieldRef Name="ID" />
    </OrderBy>
  </Query>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
    <FieldRef Name="User" />
    <FieldRef Name="Permissions" />
  </ViewFields>
  <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
  <JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink>
  <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
  <Toolbar Type="Standard"/>
</View>
```

Comment: Is this XML? If yes, use an XML parser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XDocument` to load the string as xml and then use Linq to get the values.

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(str);
  var res = doc
             .Descendants("ViewFields")
             .Descendants("FieldRef")
             .Select(x => x.Attribute("Name").Value);
```

Comment: This will also include `FieldRef` from `Query`

Comment: @w.b Ah, missed that. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

This returns only `FieldRef`s from `ViewFields`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var results = doc.Root.Element("ViewFields").Elements("FieldRef")
                 .Select(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Load method is trying to load xml from a file and LoadXml from a string

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);

    string xpath = "View/Query/ViewFields";
    var nodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes(xpath);

    foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes)
    {
       var arr = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("//FieldRef").Value;
    }
```